# Esri 4.3 maps not loading in salesforce VF page

Tags: visualforce, css

Has anyone tried using esri arcgis4.3 in vf page?
I am trying to display a basemap , but the CSS wont load.

A blank page is loaded.
If i remove the CSS tag from my script , I get the basemap like this

[image]

```
<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" 
    standardStylesheets="false" docType="HTML-5.0" applyHtmlTag="true">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-
    scalable=no" />
    <title>Get started with MapView - Create a 2D map</title>   

    <style>
    {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/"></script> 

    <script>
    require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Map, MapView){
    var map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets"
    });
    var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",  
    map: map,  
    zoom: 4,  
    center: [15, 65]  
    });
    });
    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Purple, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. It is very difficult to help you when you provide this level of detail. Can you please **[edit]** your post to include more information? Screenshots would be helpful, as well as any error messages from your browser's developer console. With that data, someone who has never used this library might still be able to help you.

Comment: You might consider also adding your markup to the question. Specifically, the attributes on your `<apex:page>` tag.

Comment: @AdrianLarson  , Hope these details are sufficient. Is there any luck?